# Open view in another tab - iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, navigation

I want to allow the user to click on a button in "tab A" and have it move to "tab B". Is this possible?

Thanks,
 William

Comment: It is possible, but I don't have the code at hand. Will post it here when I get home if someone else hasn't done already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the responses, I actually discovered that this could be done using:

```
self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = numberOfTabToPopTo;
```

Using the below code to then tidy the controller up leaving:

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];
```

Answer (score 0):

"removeFromSuperview" then "addToSubview".